# What does 仕事 and もう mean in this context?

Tags: translation

I ran into this particular dialogue in this manga where a guy celebrates his day off by gaming. He says this line that kinda confuses me.

> 休みなんて
>
> もう。。。
>
> ゲームが仕事

The もうゲームが仕事 is the one I'm wondering about, and how もう is used here.
Is he saying for that his day off, gaming would be his job? Does もう mean "already" in this context?

Comment: Could you share the picture, or could you describe where the line breaks and which text belong to the same balloon in detail? For now I doubt もう and ゲームが仕事 belong to the same sentence...

Comment: I don't know the exact context, but I get the impression that he's not enjoying gaming anymore, that it's become a chore. もう can be used to express annoyance at something.

Comment: @vlumi: Yes,I think that's what the もうis about. It could also be sarcastic, though, and, people may also enjoy their work ;-) so he might still be enjoying. As it was a dialogue, if in the previous balloon his/her family member complained that he spends all his spare time gaming, he could reply like this even if he loves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't combine the second and third lines.

It's pretty hard to tell without the context but もう in this context is an interjection representing exasperation. The game is someting that is "suppsoed to be" fun but is or has become like work.